# Can someone provide an example of a $destroy event for scopes in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Can someone please provide an example of scope's $destroy event? Here is the reference documentation from http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$destroy

> **$destroy()**
>
> Removes the current scope (and all of its children) from the parent
>   scope. Removal implies that calls to $digest() will no longer
>   propagate to the current scope and its children. Removal also implies
>   that the current scope is eligible for garbage collection.
>
> The $destroy() is usually used by directives such as ngRepeat for
>   managing the unrolling of the loop.
>
> Just before a scope is destroyed a $destroy event is broadcasted on
>   this scope. Application code can register a $destroy event handler
>   that will give it chance to perform any necessary cleanup.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sunnycpp/u4vjR/2/

Here I have created **handle-destroy** directive.

```
ctrl.directive('handleDestroy', function() {
    return function(scope, tElement, attributes) {        
        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            alert("In destroy of:" + scope.todo.text);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: In this example, and using Batarang, the scope for the destroyed element is still there. Isn't that a memory leak?

Comment: The scope is not destroy, the documentation says: "Removal also implies that the current scope is eligible for garbage collection." So that in the next gc run that scope will cease to exist

Answer (score 21):

`$destroy` can refer to 2 things: method and event

## 1. method - $scope.$destroy

```
.directive("colorTag", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      value: "=colorTag"
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var colors = new App.Colors();
      element.css("background-color", stringToColor(scope.value));
      element.css("color", contrastColor(scope.value));

      // Destroy scope, because it's no longer needed.
      scope.$destroy();
    }
  };
})
```

## 2. event - $scope.$on("$destroy")

See [@SunnyShah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14416913/111438).