# How to clean up events assigned from controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, socket.io, angularjs-controller

**When**, **where** and **how** should i get rid of old event listeners when controller is not relevant anymore?

Consider [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) with two routes: `/login` and `/loggedin`

```
app.factory('socket', ['$window', function(window) {
    return window.io();
}]);
app.controller('loginController', ['socket', function (socket) {
    this.tryLogin = function(credentials) {
        socket.emit('login', credentials);
    }
    sokcet.on('loginResponse', function(data) {
        if (data.status == 'OK') {
            // Navigate to loggedInController
        } else {
            // Show error message and keep listening - user might try again
        }
    });
}]);
app.controller('loggedInController', ['socket', function (socket) {/* Logged in, but loginController is still listening for loginResponse */}]);
```

**Problems:**

- When navigating to `/loggedin` then `loginResponse` event keeps listening
- When navigating back to `/login` page **new** listener gets added (effectively i have 2 listeners now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at Angular's [`$scope.$on('$destroy')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416894/provide-an-example-of-scopes-destroy-event) event and use it together with socket.io's [`removeListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092624/socket-io-removing-specific-listener) method. Something like this:

```
app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', 'socket', function ($scope, socket) {
    this.tryLogin = function(credentials) {
        socket.emit('login', credentials);
    }

    socket.on('loginResponse', loginResponse);

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        socket.removeListener('loginResponse', loginResponse);
    });

    function loginResponse(data) {
        if (data.status == 'OK') {
            // Navigate to loggedInController
        } else {
            // Show error message and keep listening - user might try again
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Now i have same problem with `$destory` event, don't i? Correct me if i'm wrong, still learning angular..

Comment: Ohh, $scope destorys with all listeneres attached to it?

Comment: When a scope is destroyed in Angular all associated `$on` event handlers are [destroyed along with it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27016855/2039244).

Comment: Okay, thank you good Sir, 3 minutes tili can accept the answer :)