# AddEventListener with Angular and remove it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I needed to add an event listener into an Angular application. An external plugin is listening that event to trigger some action.

I did that :

```
$window.addEventListener('itemLoaded', itemLoaded, false);
```

It works but I don't find a way to remove that event when I change my state (I use ui-router).

Do you know a better way into Angular to add that event and remove it, if my state change ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this code is being called inside of a controller, you could listen for a `$scope.$destroy()` event and then remove the listener when the controller unloads.

```js
// Inside some controller
var listener = function listen() {...};
var element = document;

element.addEventListener('click', listener)

$scope.$on('$destroy', function(event, object) { 
    element.removeListener('click', listener);
})
```

here's the [plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/gosqMH7abdQXAOUTOJZd?p=info)

Comment: Yes, I'm calling that into a controller. Can you please write me the code to remove that event? I tried the 'removeEventListener()' but its seems not working...

Comment: there's good mention of it here .. [stack post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416894/provide-an-example-of-scopes-destroy-event). You might have to attach you "itemLoaded" function to the controllers scope and then remove it by name inside of that $destroy event.

this is the best i could come up with for now .. [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gosqMH7abdQXAOUTOJZd?p=info)

Comment: `
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(e){
        $window.removeEventListener('itemLoaded', itemLoaded);
});
`

Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ui-router you can check the current state with `$state.current.url`. If the current url changes you can remove the event. You can even use `$watch` in the routing file to check whether state changed or not

Comment: Thanks for that tip, my issue is more related to the code to remove my events listener I can't find...