# How to destroy scope manually in angularjs if element is removed from javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am inserting angular template to element.
Consider following example,

```html
<p>
  <c ng-controller="ctrl">
    ...
  </c>
</p>
```

if I remove c from javascript. 
What will be side effects? (scope leaks)
How to avoid this?

I have used this,

```js
function render() {
    var lastScope = angular.element('c').scope();
            
    if(lastScope) {
        lastScope.$destroy();
    }

    $('c').remove();

    getTemplate(context + '/c.html', function(template) {
        if (template) {
            angular.element(document).injector().invoke(['$compile', '$rootScope', function($compile, $rootScope) {
                $('p').append($compile(template)($rootScope));
                $rootScope.$apply();
            }]);
        } 
    });
}
```

when I click tab render function get called everytime.
Any other sugestions?

Comment: You can avoid this using ng-if, with removes completely the element and scope

Answer (score 9):

create new scope and destroy it like:

```
var newScope = $rootScope.$new(true);
$compile(template)(newScope);

//later
newScope.$destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$scope.$on("$destroy",destroyScope);

$scope.destroyScope =function(){
// here you can delete your this function will be called whenever you move out from you controller here you can destroy you scope
 $('c').remove();
 delete $scope.var1;
}
```

it is awlays good practice to define your scope variable as object like

```
$scope.currentControllerscope ={}
$scope.currentControllerscope.myVar1 ="string"
$scope.currentControllerscope.myVar2 ="string2"
```

so that you can destryo whole object like

```
delete $scope.currentControllerscope
```

Similar question is here 
[Provide an example of scope's $destroy event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416894/provide-an-example-of-scopes-destroy-event)