# Destroy scope in $destroy event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Found this code one of the directives in a project I'm working on:

```
element.on('$destroy', function () {
    scope.$destroy();
});
```

Is this code needed? Or can I remove it? Isn't scope destroyed when directive is destroyed?

Comment: I was using something like that when worked on a subcomponent for a website, some of the elements were removed by parent application outside of our angular app and that was only way to destroy some bindings and listeners

Comment: The only point I see - if this is scope of another element. This is still sh**, but may do something.

Comment: the code was calling compile/append of another directive, but I've remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep that there unless you identify it's purpose, `$destroy()` actually removes the scope from its parent scope, below is the excerpt of official documentation

> $destroy();
>   Removes the current scope (and all of its children) from the parent scope. Removal implies that calls to $digest() will no longer propagate to the current scope and its children. Removal also implies that the current scope is eligible for garbage collection.

Also Please check this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416894/provide-an-example-of-scopes-destroy-event) for example and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write this code.

As per the docs, the `$destroy` event is triggered in two cases.

- Just before a scope is destroyed
- **Just before an element is removed from the DOM**

---

As a side note, you can still use the `scope` of the element in the `element.on('$destroy')` event **before** the scope will be destroyed:

```
element.on('$destroy', function() {
    console.log('RIP', scope);
});
```